# clang-format stack all if-statement arguments if they are too long

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

I have an `if` statement that has several `or`ed arguments. I have stacked them vertically as below for readability.

```
    if (health.flag_a || 
       health.flag_b ||
       health.flag_c ||
       health.flag_d ||
       health.flag_e ||
       health.flag_f ||
       health.flag_g ||
       health.flag_h ||
       health.flag_i ||
       health.flag_k) {
    do_something();
    return false;
}
```

`clang-format` converts this to:

```
if (health.flag_a || health.flag_b || health.flag_c || health.flag_d || health.flag_e || health.flag_f || health.flag_g || health.flag_h ||
    health.flag_i || health.flag_k) {
    do_something();
    return false;
}
```

I want `clang-format` to stack them like above if they don't fit on one line.
I expected `BinPackArguments` do this, but I'm not having any luck.

Can this be achieved?

See my `.clang-format` below.

Thanks for your help.

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  Google
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
ColumnLimit:     145
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Auto
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          ForIndentation
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've found is usage pair of `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` comments. E.g.

```
// clang-format off
if (health.flag_a || 
   health.flag_b ||
   health.flag_c ||
   health.flag_d ||
   health.flag_e ||
   health.flag_f ||
   health.flag_g ||
   health.flag_h ||
   health.flag_i ||
   health.flag_k) {
do_something();
return false;
}
// clang-format on
```

Yes, this is not a solution at all, but at least it prevents your stacked conditions from being re-formatted by `clang-format`.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can achieve something like it with `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators`. Try setting this value to `NonAssignment`. This will put your `||` operators *before* each additional condition, though, not after them.

Comment: Having `||` before the conditions is fine, what I care about is that the conditions are stacked. Your suggestion is an improvement, together with `BinPackArguments: false`. Unfortunately it only stacks the conditions that do not fit on the first line. There are still several on the first line. I thought `BinPack*` was supposed to do exactly that.

Comment: `BinPack*` are for parameters and arguments to _functions_. I don't think it looks at the conditions in branching statements.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be the case.